Is it possible to download the large file using the Google Drive API?
Let's assume the file ID of a slide file on Google Drive is "A00001". By specifying this file ID, I was able to download the file via the export feature of the Google Drive API using the following implementation.
$fileId     = 'A00001';
$outputPath = '/path/to/slide.pptx';

$response = $this->driveService->files->export($fileId, 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation');
$body     = $response->getBody();

if ($body->isSeekable()) {
    $body->rewind();
}

$file      = fopen($outputPath, 'w');
$chunkSize = 1024 * 1024;

while (!$body->eof()) {
    $chunk = $body->read($chunkSize);

    fwrite($file, $chunk);
}

fclose($file);

However, when the file size becomes large, I encounter the "exportSizeLimitExceeded" error.
message: This file is too large to be exported.
domain: global
reason: exportSizeLimitExceeded

The requirement is to download a file that is 30MB or larger.
While I understand that there are size limits, when I download the file in PPTX format from the Google Drive GUI, it takes some time to start downloading, but the download is successful.
Is there any way to avoid this error and download the large file using the Google Drive API?

This question is similar to: Google Drive Rest Api Files export limitation. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Since the question does not include any code examples, I couldn’t determine whether the issue is impossible to resolve using the REST API or if a solution might exist depending on the implementation of the PHP client library and the PHP program. I asked this question in hopes of finding any clues specifically related to implementation in PHP.
